# Persist relation to a class (and not a class instance) in Ruby on Rails with Mongoid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Assume my users can subscribe to several plan_types. I want to define those plans as classes, and be able to keep, for each user, a reference to a subscription_plan and also a presubscription_plan. This is like a State pattern :

```
class Payment::SubscriptionPlan
  def self.max_subscription_quantity
    120
  end 
end

class Payment::ConcretePlan1 < Payment::SubscriptionPlan
  def self.commitment_period
    2.months
  end
end

class Payment::ConcretePlan2 < Payment::SubscriptionPlan
  def self.max_subscription_quantity
    50
  end
end
```

What is the best way to "persist" the relation to a class in the database ? Currently I was doing the following using the `as_enum` gem

```
class Settings
  setting :subscription_plans, type: Array, default: [
    Payment::ConcretePlan1, 
    Payment::ConcretePlan2
  ]
end

class User
  as_enum :subscription_plan, Settings.subscription_plans, map: :string
  as_enum :presubscription_plan, Settings.subscription_plans, map: :string

  def subscription_plan
    return nil if super.nil?
    Payment.const_get(super.to_s.demodulize)
  end

  def presubscription_plan
    return nil if super.nil?
    Payment.const_get(super.to_s.demodulize)
  end
end
```

The current implementation works but I'm not sure this is the best way to tackle the problem

Comment: ConcretePlan1 has a subscription period where as the other plans do not. Shouldn't all plans also have a subscription period? If these classes are just placeholders for returning a particular value, you can have that same functionality?

Comment: Some payment systems involve automatic payment where I need to specify a period (eg. Stripe), whereas some other subscriptions are managed from the outside. I have factories to handle the subscriptions but I need to save the type of subscription for that :D

And actually no commitment_period is a bit different than the subscription period : for monthly payment, our offer stipulates that you have to pay for at least 3 months when you start a subscription. When paying yearly, no such commitment period apply.

Answer (score 1):

It works that's for sure.

But enums could just as easily be defined in the database. Now that you've already got it working with enums, I would say stick with enums untill you have a good reason to change it.

anyways, here's how i probably would have done it:

e.g.

- user has_many subscription_plans
- subscription_plan can belong to many users.
- Limit the ability for a user to have a max of two, one of each type. Or the user must have two at any one time etc.

[image]

You get the picture. You can change the subscription plan table to suit your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks. I'm using a class object on my server since I need to define methods on the subscription_plan (`subscription_plan.max_quantity`, etc.) which is why I want to initialize some Ruby object where I can add whatever methods I want. I edited my example to include this. I'm not just using this as string enum.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris: You should be able to still add methods and behavior specific to a kind of plan. ActiveRecord allows you to specify a "descriminator" column to instantiate a particular concrete class, giving you some of the benefits of polymorphism.

Comment: Also just realized the OP has a "mongo-db" tag.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really need subscription plans to be data-driven. The methods you are defining on the concrete types are really just data. No need for concrete types. You need a better database table (and I use the term "table" loosely since you tagged the question with mongodb):

```
| id | name   | max_subscription_quantity | commitment_period_num | commitment_period_type |
| 1  | Plan 1 | 120                       | 2                     | Month                  |
| 2  | Plan 2 | 50                        | NULL                  | NULL                   |
```

There really isn't a need for sub classes. Just one class ought to do it:

```
class Payment::SubscriptionPlan
  def commitment_period
    # return period based on type and number
  end
end
```

The only thing you need to define is `commitment_period` which does the calculation of the `commitment_period_num` and `commitment_period_type` columns.